# how to display filtering option for picklist values to successfully get the records in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, picklist, wrapper-class, repeat, criteria-filter

I am trying to build one Visualforce page where I am able to get all approval history information. But I am not able to provide users the opportunity to filter records based on "Status". Status is a picklist field that is Pending, Approved, Rejected, or Removed. Also, another requirement is to provide all similar record names in a single column(Meaning to say if there are 6 status values for a single record name, so for one column only one record name will appear). currently, I am getting the same record name 6 times.

**Below the code:**

```
<apex:page controller="Approvers">
    <apex:pageblock title="Approvals Report">
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!wrapList}" var="wrap">
            <apex:column headervalue="Name">
                <apex:facet name="header">Record</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputlink value="/{!wrap.RecordId}">{!wrap.RecordName}</apex:outputlink>
                <apex:outputText value="/{!wrap.RecordId}"  escape="false"/> 

        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputtext value="{!wrap.Status}"></apex:outputtext>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Step Status</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputtext value="{!wrap.StepStatus}"></apex:outputtext>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Is Step Pending</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputtext value="{!wrap.IsPending}"></apex:outputtext>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Step Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputtext value="{!wrap.StepName}"></apex:outputtext>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Object</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputtext value="{!wrap.RecordObject}"></apex:outputtext>
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Assigned To</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputtext value="{!wrap.AssignedToName}"></apex:outputtext>
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Approver Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputtext value="{!wrap.ApproverName}"></apex:outputtext>
        </apex:column>
        
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Date</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputtext value="{!wrap.CreatedDate}"></apex:outputtext>
        </apex:column>

    </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageblock>

</apex:page>
```

Now the Apex controller code is given below:

```
public class Approvers{

List<WrapperClass> wrapList = new List<WrapperClass>();
public List<WrapperClass> getWrapList() {

    for (ProcessInstance pi: [SELECT Id, Status, TargetObjectId, TargetObject.Name, 
                              (SELECT Id, ActorId, Actor.Name, OriginalActorId, OriginalActor.Name, IsPending,StepStatus, Comments, ProcessNode.Name, CreatedDate 
                                      FROM StepsAndWorkitems 
                                      ) 
                              FROM ProcessInstance 
                              
                              ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC] ) {

       for (ProcessInstanceHistory pih : pi.StepsAndWorkItems) {
           wrapperClass pendingApprovalWrap = new wrapperClass();
           pendingApprovalWrap.Status = pi.Status;
           pendingApprovalWrap.StepStatus = pih.StepStatus;
           pendingApprovalWrap.IsPending = pih.IsPending;
           pendingApprovalWrap.StepName = pih.ProcessNode.Name;
           pendingApprovalWrap.RecordName = String.valueOf(pi.TargetObject.Name);
           pendingApprovalWrap.RecordId = String.valueOf(pi.TargetObjectId);
           pendingApprovalWrap.RecordObject = String.valueOf(pi.TargetObjectId.getSObjectType()).split('__')[0];
           pendingApprovalWrap.AssignedToName = String.valueOf(pih.OriginalActor.Name);
           pendingApprovalWrap.ApproverName = pih.Actor.Name;
           pendingApprovalWrap.CreatedDate = String.valueOf(pih.CreatedDate);

           wrapList.add(pendingApprovalWrap);
       }          
   }

   return wrapList;
}
public class WrapperClass{
    public String Status {get; set;}
    public String StepStatus {get; set;}
    Public boolean IsPending{get; set;}
    public String StepName {get; set;}        
    public String RecordName {get; set;}
    public String RecordId {get; set;}
    public String RecordObject {get; set;}
    public String AssignedToName {get; set;}
    public String ApproverName {get; set;}
    public String CreatedDate {get; set;}
}
}
```